# Swap bytes within an unsigned long (8 bytes) in C

Tags: c, byte

```
unsigned long swap_bytes(unsigned long n) {
    unsigned char bytes[8];
    unsigned long temp;
    bytes[0] = (n >> ??) & 0xff;
    bytes[1] = (n >> ??) & 0xff; 
    // ...
}
```

I am really confused on how to shift an 8 byte `unsigned long` from
 ex: `0x12345678deadbeef` to `0x34127856addeefbe`. I started this but I am now stuck. Please help.

Comment: `unsigned long` is probably not wide enough to hold `0x12345678deadbeef `. Do you mean `unsigned long long` ?

Comment: Continue as you started. Shift and mask each byte into the array, and build the result in a complementary manner. `unsigned` was a good choice.

Comment: `long` is *at least* the size of `int`. I suggest you `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long))` to establish that.

Comment: It is suppose to be unsigned long. But what do I shift it by, is the problem that I have. Also, I am not sure if 0xff is the correct mask. I don't like shifting and masking because it confuses me but that is the only way I am allowed to approach this function.

Comment: If you need a specific width, use fixed width types, don't rely on standard types having a specific width.

Answer (score 5):

You can mask every other byte, in both versions, using `&` binary AND.
Then shift both masked values, in opposite directions and combine them using `|` binary OR.

```
n =   ((n & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00ull)>>8ull)
    | ((n & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffull)<<8ull);
```

In case it is 4byte (what I consider an `unsigned long` in contrast to the `unsigned long long`, but that is implementation specific), then the code is

```
n =   ((n & 0xff00ff00ul)>>8ul)
    | ((n & 0x00ff00fful)<<8ul);
```

Comment: Great one-liner!

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thank you so much. But why does my value of n show as 4050765991979987505? Instead of 12345678deadbeef? The swapped answer is 3978988777685397810 instead of 34127856addeefbe. Why is that?

Comment: Study the printf docu to find out how to print all kinds of sizes and if so desired in hex. In my test I used `printf("%I64x\n", n);`, with gcc windows.

Comment: @dp123 Are you sure that `sizeof(unsigned long)` is `8` on your machine? If not it may overflow which may be the reason for incorrect output.

Comment: Is there a way i can convert the n to hex before return?

Comment: Please make a separate question with the details of what you want to achieve. Hex and decimal are representations, you get them by parameterising printf accordingly, the stored value is identical. That is as long as you do not store them as a sequence of characters in a "string".

Comment: @J....S Yes, I checked it in gcc using: cpp -dD /dev/null | grep __SIZEOF_LONG__ i got  #define __SIZEOF_LONG__ 8

Comment: Still better off using `<stdint.h>` with `uint64_t` for unsigned 64bit integers (and `UINT64_C` for defining unsigned 64bit integer constants).

Comment: @ndim True, that's what I did in my test to ensure 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
void swap(char *ptr, int i, int j)
{
    char temp=*(ptr+i);
    *(ptr+i)=*(ptr+j);
    *(ptr+j)=temp;
}
int main()
{
    //unsigned long n = 0x12345678deadbeef;
    uint64_t n = 0x12345678deadbeef;

    char *ptr=(char *)&n;

    swap(ptr, 0, 1);
    swap(ptr, 2, 3);
    swap(ptr, 4, 5);
    swap(ptr, 6, 7);
}
```

The address of `n` is cast into a `char` pointer and stored in `ptr`.

`ptr+i` will give the address of the `i`th byte of `n` whose value (ie, `*(ptr+i)`) is modified appropriately by the `swap()` function.

Edit: If you are not sure if your `unsigned long`'s size is 8 bytes, you could use `uint64_t` from `inttypes.h`.

Comment: I think you should edit to use `uint_64` instead of `long`.

Comment: ... or even `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

universal & horrible

```
void swapbytes(void *p, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t tmp, *ptr = p;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (size - 1); i += 2)
    {
        tmp = *(ptr + i);
        *(ptr + i) = *(ptr + i + 1);
        *(ptr + i + 1) = tmp;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
uint64_t n;


swapbytes(&n, sizeof n);
```

Comment: What's wrong with OPs approach using shifts? After all they are not implementation-specific and don't invoke undefined behaviour like your first approach. Horrible - indeed.